# How to convert List of tuples (with 4 elements) into tuple of lists

Tags: scala, tuples

I have a list of tuples as follows:

```
List[(Obj1, Obj2, Obj3, Obj4)]
```

How can I convert it into:

```
(List[Obj1], List[Obj2], List[Obj3], List[Obj4])
```

If I had only 3 elements, then I could use `unzip3`.
What is the approach in this case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
l.foldLeft((List[Obj1](),List[Obj2](),List[Obj3](),List[Obj4]())){
  case ((la,lb,lc,ld),(a,b,c,d)) => (a :: la, b :: lb, c :: lc, d :: ld)
}
```